# Are there any PbtA games for Contemporary Fantasy and Magic?

Tags: magic, fantasy, powered-by-the-apocalypse, modern

I'm being (late) introduced to PbtA games and I'm looking for a **Contemporary Fantasy and Magic** option, something like *Ars Magica, Mage The Ascension, Dresden Files*?

Let me narrow down the question a bit...

I know we have *Monsterhearts*, but it is about relationships and lack Skins for magic users. What I am looking is something with more freedom (make your own spells) and combat/explosions or at least rituals.

I'm a huge fan of games likes *Mage* and *Dresden Files*, but I like how *PbtA* plays with conflicts and tests and I can imagine a `6-` resulting in a chaotic backslash when failing to cast a spell.

Any PbtA game I can use for that?

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil If you disagree with policy, please put that effort into meta. Asking a user to lie to us to make a question on-topic isn't constructive.

Comment: For anyone else who has good recommendations, the forums list linked above includes our own [chat]. I'd suggest leaving them there.

Comment: Ok, I see the reasons why game recommendations (game-rec) are not on-topic for SE. Thanks for the links from the moderators. I'll ask the questions in the forums or chat and I'm also ok with deleting this one, as it does not provide much help for who finds it in the future.